# How to pass two variables in Ajax using PHP PDO

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

Index.php
`<ul id="remove_row">

<button type="button" name="btn_more" data-vid="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>" id="btn_more" class="btn btn-success form-control">more</button>
</ul>`

load_data.php

```
sleep(1);
require_once("config.php");  
$query = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM county WHERE sof_similar > ".$_POST['last_video_id']." LIMIT 2");  
$query->execute();
while ($row_posts = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{ 
$pro_id = $row_posts['sof_id'];
$pro_similar = $row_posts['sof_similar'];
echo " <li>
<div class='alter'>
<h1><hr /><img src='$pro_fimagelink' alt=''> <a href='$pro_downloadpage'><strong>$pro_name</strong></a> &nbsp;<a rel='nofollow' href='?q=$pro_name' target='_self'><small></small></a> <br />
<span>$pro_shortdescription<br />
<div class='license'>$pro_license</div>


<li id="remove_row">  
<button type="button" name="btn_more" data-vid=". $pro_similar ." id="btn_more" class="btn btn-success form-control">more</button>
</li>
";
```

Ajax script:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
$(document).on('click', '#btn_more', function(){  
var last_video_id = $(this).data("vid");  
$('#btn_more').html("Loading...");  
$.ajax({  
url:"/load_data.php",  
method:"POST",  
data:{last_video_id:last_video_id},
dataType:"text",  
success:function(data)  
{  
if(data != '')  
{  
$('#remove_row').remove();  
$('#load_data_table').append(data);  
}  
else  
{  
$('#btn_more').html("No Data");  
}  
}  
});  
});  
});
```

With this code, i can pass single variable to get the result, but i need 2 variables to get the result by using AJAX. I have the base code from this blog: http://www.webslesson.info/2016/02/how-to-load-more-data-using-ajax-jquery.html

Thanks to webslesson.info to giving this opportunity to learn about AJAX.

Comment: Do some thing like this. **data : { last_video_id:last_video_id , nextVar:nextVar },**

Answer (score 0):

You can pass as many variable as you want in `ajax()` data like:

```
data:{
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
  key3: value3,
  and so on
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
data:{last_video_id:last_video_id,your_second_variable:your_second_variable},
```

Answer (score 0):

**Way-1:**

```
dataType : "json",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
data:{
       key1: value1,
       key2: value2,
       key3: value3,
       ..........
},
```

**Way-2:**  You can set data by concatenation like

```
data: 'value1='+val1+'&value2='+val2,
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see file by file.

In file `load.php` seems you're using PDO however *wrong way*. PDO allows you to securely escape variables passing to query in order to avoid [sql injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). hHaving in mind that you should refactor your current query:

```
$query = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM county WHERE sof_similar > ".$_POST['last_video_id']." LIMIT 2");
```

to

```
$query = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM county WHERE sof_similar > LIMIT 2");   
$stmt->bind_param('ii', intval($_POST['last_video_id']));
```

See more about PDO prepared statements in [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

In order to pass more variables from ajax request you could just add more key/value pair to your current [Json Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) in `Ajax script` file:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/load_data.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{ last_video_id:last_video_id, key : value }, // Our new key/value  pair here
    dataType:"text",
    success:function(data)
    {
        if(data != '')
        {
            $('#remove_row').remove();
            $('#load_data_table').append(data);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#btn_more').html("No Data");
        }
    }
});
```

And later we can access such data in `load_data.php` by reading in from `$_POST` global variable as you did with `last_video_id``.

Comment: Thanks... then, how can i assign 2 variable in PHP to get Ajax result , since i am completely newbie for PHP & AJAX... Still in learning phase...<ul id="remove_row">

<button type="button" name="btn_more" data-vid="<?php echo $pro_id; ?>" id="btn_more" class="btn btn-success form-control">more</button>
</ul>

Comment: Thanks, almost i have done. But, still I am getting error in load_data.php.  How can i get 2 variable values from $_post global variable.          $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_video WHERE video_id > ".$_POST['last_video_id']." AND video_cat = ".$_POST['last_soft_id']." LIMIT 2";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
{  
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
     {